# Which recursive formula is more complex?

Tags: complexity-theory, master-theorem

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n
```

`= O(n2)` using master theorem.

Is the above more complex than the one below?

```
T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n2
```

both are `O(n2)` using master theorem,
but I do not know how to check the constant.

Comment: There have been several similar questions asked recently... homework?

Comment: This looks like homework so I added the tag for you.

Comment: you just said yourself they are both `n²`. so they have the same complexity.

Comment: right! they r the same. I forget that! LOL

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Easier question: which one has higher complexity? 4N<sup>2</sup> or 5N<sup>2</sup>

Comment: which constant are you trying to check?

Comment: i just wish to check which recurrence formulas are faster.

Comment: Right, but for some reason you're trying to check whether Theta(n^2) is faster than Theta(n^2)